# How can I run tests on RoR faster?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

I'm using Ruby on Rails 3 and writing tests but it's too slow.
Is there some good configure or tools to make that faster?

Comment: If you're using RSpec you can bootstrap with [Spork](http://rubygems.org/gems/spork)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @eml says, if you're using RSpec, you can use Spork.  This basically fires up the environment (which is the slow part) and then keeps it around, forking every time you run your specs.

For a more general solution to the "environment always loaded" problem can install [rails-sh](https://github.com/jugyo/rails-sh) and run your tests from within the shell.

Side-note: Ruby 1.9.3 should alleviate this problem slightly as the require time has been optimized.

Answer (score 4):

Probably the biggest speed gain comes from being careful not to hit the database unless you need to.  Mock objects rather than fetch them from the database, and/or (if you are using factory girl for example) use Factory.build(:stuff) instead of Factory(:stuff) wherever possible.  Only when you have done that should you start trying to optimise further with spork

Update:
Personally, I'm also starting to think that you should not become to hung up about the speed of your tests anyway.  Faster is obviously better, but as an application grows, the test suite will grow, and however careful you are it will eventually become slower than you would like.  I'm coming to rely more and more on the autotest gem which tests changing code and works in the background (guard-rspec does a similar job).  By the time your app reaches 1000 tests you will not want to wait for the whole suite to finish every time you make a change, however fast the tests run.

Comment: Great advice. I really appreciate code where you can tell a developer has taken care in this area. My only caveat, I wouldn't necessarily insist on fast tests as a requisite for Spork. Especially when executing a small set of select specs often, where loading the rails environment can be a real impedance.

Comment: Fair point - I guess it's horses for courses really - I was reacting to one of the other answers that seemed to suggest that spork was some sort of silver bullet ... I don't suppose this is what the writer intended, but I thought that it was a bit misleading

Answer (score 2):

IMHO the main slowing part of the testing is the default configuration of fixtures. If your configuration is (in `test/test_helper.rb`):

```
class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  self.use_transactional_fixtures = false
  self.pre_loaded_fixtures = false
  self.use_instantiated_fixtures  = true
```

then before each test *method* your test database is cleaned from old data, all the tables are populated, all the records are read into memory.

If you change the settings to the opposite:

```
class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  self.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  self.pre_loaded_fixtures = true
  self.use_instantiated_fixtures  = false
```

then the database is recreated only once for each test file, and you load only the records you really need in each test method.

It depends on the size of your testing dataset whether you find the time of test database creation acceptable. When I had some pretty big set of test data, I loaded the fixtures only once, before the whole test suite, but that project was (is) in Rails 1, and I have modified it heavily, so I cannot tell how to do it in Rails 3 (at least until the problem starts to be painful in some new project ;).

There is a neverending discussion whether tests should hit the database or not. If you believe that they should (since the database cooperation should also be tested), then you may check whether just setting these parameters helps you (or anyone reading these answers).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend `Spork` and `Guard`, both of them can work perfectly with `RSpec`.

`Spork` can help you to run tests more quickly, 
http://railscasts.com/episodes/285-spork

`Guard` can help you to run tests automatically.
http://railscasts.com/episodes/264-guard

Answer (score 0):

Try to develop so that most of your tests can be executed without needing to load the entire Rails application framework. In your spec helper, skip loading the environment or rpec/rails if only fast tests are being executed, something like...

```
# /spec/spec_helper.rb
if RSpec.configuration.inclusion_filter[:fast]
  # Setup required for fast tests in particular (if any)
  # ...
else
  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
  require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
  require 'rspec/rails'

  Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # ...

  unless RSpec.configuration.inclusion_filter[:fast]
    # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
    # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
    # instead of true.
    config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  end
end
```

To mark a test as "fast", add the `, :fast => true` option to its `it` call or to a surrounding `describe` call.

To run only the fast tests, execute `rspec --tag fast` from your command shell.

It can be hard to figure out how to structure your code so that tests can be run separately from Rails (and of course, you'll still want to have functional and integration tests that don't run separately).

One trick in my arsenal is to avoid directly writing code on an ActiveRecord model or other such class, and prefer writing it on a mixin module instead. You can test the mixin module by defining Subject to be an object that is extended by that module...

```
describe 'MyModule', :fast => true
  subject{ Object.new.tap{|o| o.extend MyModule} }

  it 'does something' do
    # ...
  end
end
```